# Can I bind single keys in zsh when in vi normal mode?

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts, vi-mode

I use urxvt with zsh and vi keys (`bindkey -v`). Is there a way to bind custom commands to single keys when in normal mode? For example, I'd like `p` to run `xclip -o -sel clip` and insert the result at the cursor position.

Comment: Line edition is done by the shell (zsh), not by the terminal (urxvt).

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for the info. Do you know of a way to realize that with zsh?